# Retreive data from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying (without success) to retrieve a list of users in a group from a Firebase database; and I was wondering if its possible based on my data structure (below), or is the problem my swift code (also below)

This is my Firebase structure:

```
Users
---- <UserID>
---------- Username
---------- Email
---------- etc...
Groups
---- <GroupID>
---------- GroupName
---------- CreationDate
---------- GroupAdmin
---------- etc...
UsersInGroups
------- UserID
---------- GroupID : true   <---- User is in Group
```

With the above data structure is it possible for me to retrieve the list of all `users` in the a particular `group`?

Currently my swift code is as follows:

```
ref = Database.database()reference(withPath: "UsersInGroups")
handle = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: <userID>).queryEqual(toValue: true).observe(.value, ....
```

As you can imagine, it is not pulling the `userID` where the `groupID = true`!?

Lastly, I was wondering if this is possible: I would like to get a list of all the `GroupEntries` a User has done.

the Firebase structure is as follows:

```
GroupEntry
-------- <GroupID>
--------------- <entryID> : <userID>
```

the  is a dynamic and unique string (ex 3:8) and the userID is the user that created the entry.

The swift code is below:

```
ref = Database.database()reference(withPath: "GroupEntry")
handle = ref.child(<groupID>).queryEqual(toValue: <userID>).observe(.value, ...
```

Can anyone offer any assistance!?

Comment: Did you try using the `observe` method on your query?

Comment: Yes, I just updated the question with the `observe` portion

Comment: Does it work without the query?

Comment: This is a categorization problem. The best solution is to add an additional top-level list of `GroupUsers` (the inverse of your `UsersInGroups`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thats what I was figuring... I just didnt want to face the facts.... :(  How about the second portion, do I need to do the same thing!? I hope not!?

Answer (score 2):

You can represent the relationships between the groups and users using the following locations:

- `group-users/$groupId/$uid`
- `user-groups/$uid/$groupId`

Storing both inversions of the relationship will give you more querying abilities. To retrieve the users in a group, you observe the children at `group-users/$groupId` – on the other hand, you can get the groups a user is in by observing the children at `user-groups/$userId`.

Group entries can be represented with two more locations:

- `group-entries/$groupId/$entryId`
- `user-entries/$userId/$entryId`

You could get all the entries a user has made by observing `user-entries/$userId`; you can query further by ordering by the child that contains the entry's `$groupId`.

The challenge with all of these locations is maintaining them – ensuring that data is kept consistent throughout. This can be in a somewhat manual way using one of the Firebase client SDKs, however you could consider using Cloud Functions to create triggers that update the relevant locations in the database.